# Find the coefficient of the given term when (u^2 - v^2 ) ^10 expanded by the binomial theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The term is u^16 v^4

When (u^2 - v^2 ) ^10 is exanded by the binomial theorem.

My book uses Combinations, but I'm not sure if it works if u and v are squared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=u^2$, $y=v^2$, and you are reduced to looking for the $x^8 v^2$ term in $(x+y)^{10}$. So it makes essentially no difference that there are squares: you'll still get $\binom{10}{8}$ as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if lets say there is a constant and a coefficient other than 1. Same thing?

(2x-7+5)^8 of the term x^3 y^4